# Camel-swagger and Hawt.io incompatibility

Tags: apache-camel, swagger, hawtio

We have Camel (2.15.2) based application with some REST services published.
Camel-swagger component is used to publish information about the services.

Everything works perfectly if the app is alone in a Tomcat container.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2015:11:25:20 +0200] "GET /myapp/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 383
```

However if I deploy freshly downloaded Hawt.io 1.4.51 WAR (sample-1.4.51.war) in the same container (no changes o configurations done) I get 204 response code from my original app.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2015:12:50:51 +0200] "GET /myapp/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

I guess it all about JMX and how Swagger gets information about REST services published in the Camel context,  but I not sure how to avoid this error